# building transformation matrix from spherical to cartesian coordinate system

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

How to arrive at the following from given $ x  = r\sin \theta \cos \phi, y  = r\sin \theta \sin \phi, z=r\cos\theta $

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
A_x\\ 
A_y\\ 
A_z
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\sin \theta \cos \phi & \cos \theta \cos \phi  & -\sin\phi\\ 
\sin \theta \sin \phi & \cos \theta \sin \phi  & \cos\phi\\ 
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_r\\ 
A_\theta\\ 
A_\phi
\end{bmatrix}$$

Also how show that
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\hat i\\ 
\hat j\\ 
\hat k
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\sin \theta \cos \phi & \cos \theta \cos \phi  & -\sin\phi\\ 
\sin \theta \sin \phi & \cos \theta \sin \phi  & \cos\phi\\ 
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat e_r\\ 
\hat e_\theta\\ 
\hat e_\phi
\end{bmatrix}$$
How to change $(a,b,c)$ into spherical polar coordinates and $ (r ,\theta, \phi)$ into cartesian coordinates using this matrix?
Thank you!!

Comment: Hi @Potato can you please help me with it??

Comment: For posterity: I think one of those transformation matrices should be inverted/transposed --- the components should transform oppositely to the bases... right?

Answer (score 7):

I can partially answer this. I believe your first matrix is not the correct general transformation matrix for cartesian to spherical coordinates because you are missing factors of $\rho$ (the radial coordinate), as well as some other incorrect pieces. So it is not clear what you are trying to show.

If you are trying to derive the *general* transformation matrix from spherical to cartesian, it is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
A_x\\ 
A_y\\ 
A_z
\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}
\sin \theta \cos \phi & \rho \cos \theta \cos \phi  & -\rho \sin \theta \sin\phi\\ 
\sin \theta \sin \phi & \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi  & \rho \sin\theta \cos\phi\\ 
\cos\theta & -\rho \sin\theta  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_r\\ 
A_\theta\\ 
A_\phi
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This matrix is formed from the derivative matrix in the following way:
$
\sum_{(i,j)} \frac {\partial x^i} {\partial u^j} 
$
where
$$x^1  = \rho\sin \theta \cos \phi, x^2  = \rho\sin \theta \sin \phi, x^3=\rho\cos\theta$$
and
$u^1 = \rho, u^2 = \theta, u^3 = \phi
$
(Note: the superscripts are indices, not exponents).
If you write out all the derivatives, you get this matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_x\\ 
A_y\\ 
A_z
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac {\partial (\rho \sin \theta \cos \phi)} {\partial \rho} & 
\frac {\partial (\rho \sin \theta \cos \phi)} {\partial \theta} &
\frac {\partial (\rho \sin \theta \cos \phi)} {\partial \phi}\\ 
\frac {\partial (\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi)} {\partial \rho} & 
\frac {\partial (\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi)} {\partial \theta} &
\frac {\partial (\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi)} {\partial \phi}\\ 
\frac {\partial (\rho \cos \theta)} {\partial \rho} & 
\frac {\partial (\rho \cos \theta)} {\partial \theta} &
\frac {\partial (\rho \cos \theta)} {\partial \phi}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_r\\ 
A_\theta\\ 
A_\phi
\end{bmatrix}
$$
...which evaluates to the correct general transformation matrix I listed above.

Comment: BTW, see the inverse [in Wolfram Alpha](https://tinyurl.com/4w9btufz), but this [gets a more simplified form here](https://tinyurl.com/2p94r7sc)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use the matrix you gave for converting **position**. This matrix is used when you have a vector $\vec{A} = A_{r} \hat{r} + A_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + A_{\phi} \hat{\phi}$ and you want to rewrite it as $\vec{A} = A_{x} \hat{x} + A_{y} \hat{y} + A_{z} \hat{z}$. The matrix was obtained by stacking together $\hat{r}$, $\hat{\theta}$, $\hat{\phi}$ as columns of the transformation matrix.

Converting position from one coordinate system to another is a totally different story. You can do $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. This would let you solve for $\theta$ and then you can solve for $\phi$. I can't think of any correct way to do what you are trying to do using matrices.

Answer (score -1):

get the elements of the jacobian matrix, then divide them to their respective scale factors