# Transformation matrix from polar to cartesian coordinates

Tags: vectors, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

If the following transformation matrix of the components of a vector $\vec{A}$ from cartesian to polar coordinates is true:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}A_x\\A_y\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-r\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &r\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A_r\\A_{\theta} \end{bmatrix}
$$

(I found it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4325357),
then I have a trouble in understanding the expression for the length of $|\vec{A}|$ in polar coordinates. If I observe that

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-r\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &r\cos \theta \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \ 1 & 0\\\ 0 & r\end{bmatrix} == R \cdot g
$$

then I easily calculate
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \ A_x & A_y \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \ A_x \\\ A_y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \ A_r & A_\theta \end{bmatrix} g^{T} R^{T} R g \begin{bmatrix} \ A_r \\\ A_\theta \end{bmatrix} = A_r^2 + r^2 A_\theta^2 = |\vec{A}|$$

What on earth does this formula $|\vec{A}| = A_r^2 + r^2 A_\theta^2 $ mean? It resembles the infinitesimal line element in polar coordinates, but I don't see the meaning. Please clarify!

Comment: As the top answer states, the process of going between Cartesian and polar coordinates is not linear and therefore cannot be represented by a matrix. Cartesian coordinates and polar coordinates give two different charts on the plane in the sense of manifolds. With this perspective, you can express elements of the tangent space, cotangent space, etc in terms of these charts and use a matrix to convert back and forth between the two.

Comment: @Oiler, I see his point. But by considering infinitesimal displacement, we are referring to local basis in polar coordinates which we can apply linear transformation. Quoting "an arbitrary vector A must transform the same way as the components of the displacement do", we may conclude that the transformation matrix (P) I wrote should work. Then my question arises as to what $|\vec{A}| = A_r^2+r^2 A_{\theta}^2$ is supposed to mean?